# How to use few buttons, with dependencies between them? Android Studio

Tags: android, synchronization, android-button

I have 4 buttons, that each one of them doe's a different action (lets say each action takes 2 minutes)

When I click both buttons (with few minutes between them), both of them still get inside the 'if' part, although the flag i put.

Here is part of my code:

```
   southToNorth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            north.incCounter();
            north.setWaitingState(true);
            pushToQueue(1);

            if (isWorking==0) {
                isWorking++;
                start();
            }
        }
    });

    westToEast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            east.incCounter();
            east.setWaitingState(true);
            pushToQueue(2);

            if (isWorking==0) {
                isWorking++;
                start();
            }
        }
    });
```

I Don't think that is a synchronization problem, i even put this code at the top of the start function:

```
   private void start() {

    if(isWorking>1)
        return;
```

but still, both of them doe's all of the start function, what I'm trying to avoid.

(I have a global flag "int isWorking" initialized to zero )

Why both of them are getting inside the if part? How can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you ever setting `isWorking`? What does `pushToQueue()` do?

Comment: isWorking is initialized to 0 when running. Only when start() function is done, isWorking is set up to be 0 again.
pushToQueue responsible to make some changes on the screen, no connection to the program flow

Comment: When `start()` finishes you set `isWorking` back to zero? If your actions are asynchronous, then `isWorkng` will instantly be set back to zero. You need to listen for when the action finishes before setting `isWorking` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

A global flag should do it. You say you've tried it, but you haven't actually provided *how* you tried it, so I can't specifically help with that.

Make two variables and some static fields:

```
private static final int ACTION_NONE = -1;
private static final int ACTION_ONE = 0;
private static final int ACTION_TWO = 1;
private static final int ACTION_THREE = 2;
private static final int ACTION_FOUR = 3;

private boolean actionRunning = false;
private int queuedAction = ACTION_NONE;
```

When you try to run an action, check if there's currently an action running:

```
if (actionRunning) {
    queuedAction = /* the corresponding static field */;
} else {
    queuedAction = ACTION_NONE;
    actionRunning = true;
}
```

Then, when whatever action you're using completes, run the appropriate queued action:

```
switch (queuedAction) {
    case ACTION_ONE:
        //run action 1
        break;
    case ACTION_TWO:
       //etc
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. 
I edited my question, I hope it's more clear now